# curl/types.h file or directory not found

Tags: compiling, programming, c++, c, curl

I have a cpp code to compile but while compiling it is showing the error of

`curl/types.h file or directory not found, compilation error, fatal error.`

I am using ubuntu 12.10. please help me to fix this.
Thank you.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the `curl/types.h` library? Which function are you using?

Comment: @ green7: I want to generate the candle stick graph using CPP, actually its part of my project which will extract some information from websites and according to the statistics it will generate the respective graph, i've the code for the same, but while compiling it is showing the above error.